# WSO2 - Identity Server - How to change the "Claim Dialect" and policies that the I.S middleware uses by default

Tags: wso2, claims-based-identity, wso2-identity-server

The fact is that i'm trying to customize the "WSO2 Identity Server" according to a certain OASIS standard and i need to change the "Claim Dialect" that de middleware platform uses by default, changing the claims that define a user. After that i also want to change the policies to consider that changes.

If somebody could provide me some information related to it i would be really grateful.

P.D: I've found in this URL [WSO2 Identity Server - Cannot Use Dialect I defined in Service Provider's Claim Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33111229/wso2-identity-server-cannot-use-dialect-i-defined-in-service-providers-claim) some information related with my question but no information about policy administration.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2 Identity Server internally uses it's own dialect ("http://wso2.org/claims").

But, It can be configured to send claims in different dialect for applications from Service Provider configurations.

Can you explain your requirement in detailed?

What is the reason to change the internal dialect?

Thanks
Isura

Comment: Hi Isura, I'm trying to modify the default claim dialect (http://wso2.org/claims) to include my own personal claims according to some standard (because I've read that in the actual WSO2-IS version it's impossible to use another custom claim dialect).
I've achieved introducing new claims using the "claim-config.xml" file, but I'm having problems to provide a correct claim mapping (I don't know how to manage with the LDAP user store or with the underlying user store).
I know I can replace my nulls mapped attributes with existing ones which are supported correctly, but I want create mi own.Thanks

Comment: Yes. You  can add personal claims to wso2 dialect. You can add claims through UI as well. Mapped attribute should be supported by underline user store. You can browse the LDAP and find all available attributes in LDAP.  You can map each claim into any ldap attribute which are not currently use in other claims.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, it has been of great help to know I'm going through the good way. The fact is that I don't know which attributes are supported by the underlying user store and how to browse de LDAP to find all the available attributes (excuse me if my answer sounds stupid, but don't control too much about it). If you could give me an example about how to make it I would be greatly appreciated.Greetings.

Comment: You can find some attributes from <IS_HOME>repository/resources/identity/ldif directory. It has 3 ldiff files identityPerson, scimPerson and wso2Person. Open one file and it has attributes types supported by underline LDAP with tab "NAME"

Comment: Okey, I've achieved mapping correctly some custom claims with the attributes types supported by underline LDAP, but now my question Is this, ¿Can I introduce my own personal attributes in the "ldif" files? ¿How can I do it? I also have notice that there are claims in the http://wso2.org/claims Claim Dialect that don't appear in the "ldif" files (For example: givenName), ¿Where can I find them?